# center search bar with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code. I have a search that I want to center in the page. But for some reason it is not working.
     
    
        
            Search

```
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>ADD BUTTON HERE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <hr>
    </body>
<html>
```

I also have the following css

```
.box{
    width: 100%;
}

#search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have read numerous posts about this, and all of them to do `margin: 0 auto;` but that just isn't working. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just center anything inside the box, so as the search field also gets centered.

```css
.box{
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>ADD BUTTON HERE</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change your display from `inline-block` to `block`:

```
#search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QGJ2dcqHWNZrCRDbYXtw?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

```
.box{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:150px; /* Set this based on the size of the text box you are using */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.box{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:100px; /* Set this property to whatever you like */
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24d153gb/